# How do I run multiple program in codelite

Tags: c++, c, build, codelite

I had to do my homework with c programming in codelite. Just like codeBlock and Dev-C++ which give user to run multiple console program in the same folder, however, when I run it on codelite it fail.

I have create different **workspace** folder or even different **project**.But when I try to build it, only the first c file get to build but not later created c file.

May anyone please help me on this issues?I just want to rum multiple program in codelite just like code block.

Comment: I don't know codelite but what you are describing looks like a setting to always build the first project. Search for a setting to build current project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hitting `F7`, builds the **active** project (the project with a **bold text** in the workspace tree view).

To change the **active** project:

- Double click a project, or:
- Right click a project and select `Make active`

To build all the projects in a single click (Default key: `F7`):

- Add new project to the workspace
- Right click it and select `Build Order`
- In the dialog that pops up, click on the checkbox near each project
- Build the dummy project (make it active as described above) and hit `F7`

OR, build the entire workspace (`Ctrl-Shift-B`):

- From the menu bar select `Build -> Build Workspace` (default key bindings: `Ctrl-Shift-B`)

To execute a project (default key binding: `Ctrl-F5`):

- Make the project **active** by double clicking it
- Hit `Ctrl-F5`

NOTE:

All keybindings can be changed from `Settings -> Keyboard shortcuts`

HTH,
Eran

Comment: Thanks you for your helping hand.Thanks you so much.